# Spring Data JPA/Hibernate: How to make entities read-only incl. their lazily-loaded relationships? Without using @Immutable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

**Scenario**

A Spring Data JPA/Hibernate based application with `@Transactional` services, thus entities are managed by the persistence provider with no explicit invoking of `save`/`update`/`persist`.

Now, I'd like to implement a read-only repository/service for `MyEntity`, while also keeping the non-read-only/CRUD ones -- ergo, annotating the entity `@Immutable` will be too much and would not help.

**Approach**

Fetching entities within a read-only session (which we reset to non-read-only afterwards), here as a simplified example:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

   private long id;

   @OneToMany // lazily-loaded as per default
   private List<MyOtherEntity> otherEntities;
}
```

```
@Service
public class ReadOnlyService {

   private final Repository repository;
   private final EntityManager entityManager;

   public MyEntity findAllByIds(Collection<Long> ids) {
      return executeInReadOnlySession(() -> repository.findAllById(ids));
   }

   private <T> T executeInReadOnlySession(Supplier<T> operation) {
    Session session = getSession();
    session.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
    T result = operation.get();
    session.setDefaultReadOnly(false);
    return result;
  }

  private Session getSession() {
    return ((EntityManager) entityManager.unwrap(null)).unwrap(Session.class);
  }
}
```

**The issue with this approach**

As such, this approach works fine. However, as `MyEntity.otherEntities` is lazily-loaded, it's not being loaded within the read-only session. Once it's lazily loaded later on, the session has been reset to setDefaultReadOnly(false) and the list items in `otherEntities` are not immutable. Moreover, `MyOtherEntity` might have lazily-loaded relations itself.

**Question**

Is there a solution to make all of `MyEntity`'s lazily-loaded relationships read-only too (and also recursively all of lazily-loaded fields of `MyOtherEntity`), without having to eagerly-load them within the read-only session?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Annotate your service class like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

**Solution 2**

Make use of `JPARepository` methods. All reading methods of `SimpleJPARepository` are already annotated as read-only. Only the *save**, *delete** and *flush* methods are annotated for modification. That's what you wanted, right?

`SimpleJPARepository` is the default implementation of `JPARepository` interface and will be used after proper auto-configuration of Spring Boot Data. For example when `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency is present.